# Why printf is executed before cout after using ios::sync_with_stdio(false) in c++?

Tags: c++, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main () {
  std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::cout << "hi from c++\n";
  printf("hi from c\n");
  return 0;
}
```

After removing std::endl and putting \n instead in cout statement the output changed to the following:

```
hi from c
hi from c++
```

Comment: It's unclear, what was the printout before you changed it? There's also not even an `std::endl` in the code you posted, so I'm even more confused.

Comment: So you see a conflict between the behaviour you observe and the spec https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio ? Please explain that conflict.

Comment: "Why printf is executed before cout" - It's not executed before, the output is just written in different order due to different buffering and flushing.

Answer (score 8):

It's a buffering issue.

By default when standard output is connected to a terminal, `stdout` is *line-buffered* meaning the buffer is flushed and output actually written to the terminal on newline.

When C stdio is disconnected from the C++ standard streams, `std::cout` is *fully* buffered, meaning output is actually written when either explicitly flushed (using e.g. `std::flush` or `std::endl` manipulators) or if the buffer is full.

The two buffers used by C `stdout` and C++ `std::cout` are different and not connected.

Flushing of the buffers also happens when the program exits.

---

What happens in your program is that the output with `printf` is flushed immediately because of the trailing newline in the string. But the output to `std::cout` is only flushed when the program exits.